# Create a text cell value based on row entries and corresponding columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I understand this is a tough way of wording the problem I have. Please try and help me.
I want to create a Column called Orders which contains cells based on corresponding item values.

So if I have columns: FlatNo, Truffle, Pineapple, Mango, Chocochips; I want to create a column called Orders which has value:
FlatNo - A51
Mango - 1
Chocochips - 1

(if no values in the Pineapple & Truffle Columns, none show up in Orders columns)
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWaNW.png)

How do I do that ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Google Sheets is not Excel. Please ensure your tags are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` and `&`. `&` simply puts  the different desired things altogether.

Hope the following formula will get you the result for column orders. I have put the number of each item ordered inside parentheses before the item.

```
="Flat No. "&A2&IF(ISBLANK(B2),"","-("&B2&")"&$B$1)&IF(ISBLANK(C2),"","-("&C2&")"&$C$1)&IF(ISBLANK(D2),"","-("&D2&")"&$D$1)&IF(ISBLANK(E2),"","-("&E2&")"&$E$1)
```

For instance the third order is shown like this: `Flat No. E-23-(1)Truffle -1 Pc Rs 60-(3)Mango -1 Pc Rs 60`
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! You've really helped me out ! My instagram handle is @dakkasbakery. If you're ever in or around Pune, India, let me know. You can have any pastries or cupcakes on the house :) Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help :) I have been in India before, wonderful country and people. Please confirm my answer so it can be helpful for others with similar question.